# Geolocation : Is there are way to find if someone is going up in the altitude

Tags: javascript, ios, geolocation, compass-geolocation, air-android

I am trying to develop an application in which i have to track if people are travelling up on different floor in the building. I tried using GeolocationAPI that gives me altitude in meters above the sea level but as its a same building the lat,long is going to be the same and altitude is always same.

The languages I can use is Javascript / Actionscript trying to do a Andoid air / ios application.

Comment: If they're going up/down floors, then altitude is going to be different by about 3-4 meters. First you'd have to check what the margin of error is for the altitude measurements to see if you can even TRY to determine vertical movement down to a per-floor range.

Answer (score 3):

Meters above sealevel is what you want.  The user's height above sea level will change as they move up and down in the building.

The real challenge you are going to have is accurately measuring that.  In good conditions outside your GPS can have an accuracy around +-10 feet or so.  In most buildings the distance between floors will be 10-12 feet (of course that varies a lot). So even in best conditions you will have difficulty determining floor.  Actually in a building you will have a very difficult time getting accurate GPS at all.